# LINQ error, 'the type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect", when trying to use two joins

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have this [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) expression where I'm trying to add a second join, but I'm getting an error.

This is the query I have:

```
            from x in db.Sales
            join y in db.Sales on x.ID equals y.ID - 1
            join z in db.Locations on x.Line equals z.LocationCode
            where Convert.ToInt32(y.Order) >= Convert.ToInt32(x.Order)
            orderby x.OrderDate ascending
            select x).Distinct()
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. 
>   Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

Is there anything I need to change in that second join to not get that error?

Comment: I think the `y.ID - 1` in the first join is the culprit. I'm not sure that you can do it like that.

Comment: What are the types of `x.Line` and `z.LocationCode`?

Comment: @Maarten that's not the issue because it works just fine, I'm trying to put one more join on that Locations table in that query

Comment: @DStanley please put that as an answer so I can mark it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently `x.Line` and `z.LocationCode` are incompatible types.  You could change one or the other to an expression that would make both sides compatible.